# How to send and use an array in query, laravel

Tags: php, sql, ajax, laravel

I want to send an array of id to my controller, and use that controller in the "whereIn" clause. But it's not working. My codes are :

From View: I am using ajax call to get value for package_id[] (you can see in the form below). the values are in array.

```
   <form action="" class="price-form" method="post">
       @csrf
       <input type="text" value="" name="package_id[]" id="package_id">
       <input type="text" value="50" name="member_number" id="member_number">
       <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
```

from the controller: The product_id (in form of array) is dragged here in the controller.

```
public function get_package_price(Request $request) {

    if($request->ajax()){
        $member_number = $request->get('member_number');

        $package_ids = $request->get('package_id');

        if($member_number != '')
        {
            $get_price = DB::table('package_plans')->whereIn('package_id',$package_ids)
            ->where('user_limit', '>=', $member_number)->first();

            $get_plan_id = $get_price->id;
            $get_package_price = $get_price->price_in_usd;
            $user_limit = $get_price->user_limit;
     
        }

        $data = array(
            'get_package_price'  => $get_package_price,
            'get_plan_id'  => $get_plan_id,
            'user_limit'  => $user_limit
        );

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

Codes from script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#member_number").keyup(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var member_number = $('#member_number').val();
            var package_id = $('#package_id').val();
            fetch_package_title(package_id, member_number);

            function fetch_package_title(package_id = '', member_number = ''){
            var currency_val = $('#currency_value').val();

            $.ajax({
                url : 'get_package_price',
                method : 'GET',
                data : {package_id:package_id, member_number:member_number},
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(data){
                    console.log(data.get_package_price);
                    var final_price = data.get_package_price;
                    var price_per_member =( data.get_package_price/data.user_limit ) 
                                          *member_number;
                    $('#package_price').html(data.get_package_price);
                    $('#cost_per_seat').html(price_per_member);
                    $('#cost_per_head').val(price_per_member);
                    $('#get_plan_id').val(data.get_plan_id);
                    $('#total_price').val(price_per_member);
                }
            });
        }

      });
    });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: You get the package_id from 1 element with id `#package_id` note that you can get the full data from the form using `var data = $('form').serialize();` and use it in your ajax call . I don't really see why you would want it to post as an array if its only one value...

Answer (score 0):

`package_id[]` construction used if you have **MANY** fields. If you have **ONE** field for many values (eg 1,2,3,4) - use `package_id`

```
<input type="text" value="" name="package_ids" id="package_id">
```

```
$package_ids = $request->get('package_ids');
```